# Do we say "the stone that goes with the balloon is dirty" or "the stone that comes with the balloon is dirty"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

[image: A balloon with a weight tied to it with a string]

A seller sells a balloon. A string is tied to the balloon at one end and to a stone at the other end. The stone is used to keep the balloon from flying up.

I bought that balloon for my daughter. When we were at home, she put the balloon on to the bed. I said to her "**the stone that goes with the balloon is dirty. Don't put it on the bed**"?

I think I might say it incorrectly.

I remember we use "**come with**" to talk about a feature of a product. For example, "*This washing machine comes with a 2-year warranty*" or "*This luxury villa comes complete with its own private swimming pool.*"

I guess we use this structure "**the main product + come with + its part/feature**". So in my examples
"**This washing machine**" is the main product and "**a 2-year warranty**" is its feature and "**This luxury villa**" is the main item and "**its own private swimming pool**" is its part.

Similarly, "**the balloon**" is the main item and "**the stone**" is its part.

Can we say "**this balloon comes with a stone**"?

However, can we say "**the stone that comes with the balloon is dirty**"? because "**the stone**" is not the main part.

The opposite of "**come**" is "**go**".

Do we have this structure "**the main product's part/feature + go with + the main product**"?

For example, "**the private swimming pool that goes with the luxury villa is big**" and "**the 2-year warranty that goes with this washing machine is almost due**"

Also, I am mot sure we can use "**of**". For example, "**the stone of the balloon is dirty**" but it sounds a bit off.

Comment: I think you did a nice job of explaining your thinking behind "goes with" and "comes with". Some folks might think it's a little verbose, but I found it very clear, and I think it will be helpful to other learners.

Comment: I agree with Lambie, the stone "comes with" , is future tense, before you buy it, and after purchase it's "came with", because the tense is on the act of receiving the item. That said in this case, I'd say that 'the stone on the balloon is dirty', or 'the stone on the balloon string is dirty', as it eliminates tense and is clearer.

Comment: TimR's "came with" is most usual. "comes with" and "goes with"  are somewhat acceptable, would be fully understood, but less usual.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon But as Kate Bunting and I have both said, came with/comes with is not necessary. What parents says to a child: *the stone that goes with the balloon is dirty. Don't put it on the bed*"? comes with/goes with is pragmatically unnecessary.

Comment: Just say "The stone is dirty." Unless there are many stones on her bed, she'll know what you are referring to.

Comment: You could just say "The stone that's attached to the balloon.." or "The stone that's tied to the balloon.." Those sound more natural to me.

Comment: @Lambie  What you and Kate said is (and was) understood.  I was commenting in what the OP asked.  All the other suggestions are good enough, perhaps, but addressing the question, at least first, is often nice. "Came" is also not in the options asked about, but ... .

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The OP has asked **three questions** and the most upvoted answer **does not deal with all of them**.

Answer (score 24):

**Goes with** = belongs with.

**Comes with** = is sold with.

Neither is absolutely wrong, but since it's obvious what 'stone' you are talking about (I would call it a 'weight'), all you need say is "The stone's dirty".

Comment: goes with/comes with sounds like copy (advertising) or a discussion with the balloon seller.

Comment: I don't think "comes with" is only used for things sold together. It more like "is included". A puppy comes with a lot of obligations. That part goes with the blue widget. [Sony a9 III: Global shutter comes with an image quality cost](https://m.dpreview.com/articles/6717086661/sony-a9-iii-image-quality-dynamic-range-analysis)

Comment: @ColleenV Sure Colleen, comes with means included (aka sold with) but would you tell your daughter the stone on the string **that comes** with the balloon is dirty? Really?

Comment: @ColleenV - I didn't mean to imply that that was the _only_ meaning of 'comes with' - it happens to be the sense that Tom had mentioned!

Comment: @Lambie I chose to read the question as asking about 'goes with' versus 'comes with', and not  "what should I say to my daughter", which would be off topic. I would say "That's dirty, don't put it on your bed." but I'm not learning English as a foreign language.

Comment: @ColleenV "I bought that balloon for my daughter. When we were at home, she put the balloon on to the bed. I said to her "the stone that goes with the balloon is dirty. Don't put it on the bed"?" The daughter and dirty stone are a basic part of the context here. *How can that be off topic?* I answered all three ideas. With and without the kid. comes with/goes with does not fit the context with the child and the bed.

Comment: *I don't think "comes with" is only used for things sold together.* Are puppies not sold where you are? Sony A9 IIIs are definitely sold.

Comment: @Tashus But no one asked that. The OP asked about "goes with" and telling his daughter not to put the dirty stone on the bed. And can we say: comes with/goes with for the balloon string and stone.

Comment: @Tashus It does answer it because in the context of the entire idea and sentence spoken to a kid, this: "this balloon comes with a stone" would not be said by a most English speakers. To describe it, one would or might say: This balloon comes with a stone attached to a string. or something like that. And not: comes with a stone. Your analogy does not work because it's verbs we're discussing, not things for comes with/goes with.

Comment: OP specifically included alternative examples. Focusing on the parent-child relationship or the specific hardware involved is ignoring the actual question asked. It could be the Archbishop of Canterbury talking to Kylie Minogue about an anvil tied to a zeppelin with a gold chain and the underlying question would be the same. Everyone posting here already knows this, cranky debate over trivia is pointless. I know because I'm an expert in cranky debate over trivia.

Comment: @Tashus Just to be clear, I was talking about the question being off-topic if it was "How do I phrase this sentence?" Answers can't be off-topic. They are either answers or not answers. Any answer that attempts to address the question is an answer, and we can express whether or not we think an answer is useful through voting. I think Lambie's answer offers an interesting perspective even though I think it's better to focus on 'goes with/comes with'.

Answer (score 20):

The most idiomatic way to have referred to the stone in the vignette with your daughter:

> The stone that **came with** the balloon is dirty. Don't put it on the bed.

The present refers to the general situation:

> The stone that comes with these balloons doesn't need to be as heavy as it is. A much smaller stone would suffice.

Comment: The stone on the balloon string is dirty. There is no need to specify at all.

Comment: Whether there is a need or not is debatable.  The stone that "came with" or "is attached to the balloon" is better than "*on* the balloon".   The balloon is on a string. Is the string *on* the balloon?

Comment: I wrote: The stone on the balloon **string**. the string of the balloon. Allowable in English.

Comment: The most idiomatic way is even more debatable. This: "the stone that goes with the balloon is dirty. Don't put it on the bed"? is completely off track. Idiomaticity is not the only consideration here.

Answer (score 7):

“Come with” means “arrive together with”.  You can say it about people (“Bob came with Carol to the party”) or objects (“The hamburger came with a side of fries”).  Said about inanimate objects, the phrase often means that they are natural partners, especially one is given freely as an accessory or supplement to the other, which is paid for.  Buy a BMW, a 10-year warranty might come with it.  Buy the special, it comes with a free dessert.

“Go with” suggests that that the motion is volitional.  “Bob goes with Carol” can mean literally he went somewhere with her, or idiomatically that they are romantic partners and he goes with her to parties and movies and such.

Said about an inanimate object, it means something entirely different: that one thing is *aesthetically compatible* with the other.  Ketchup goes with fries; yellow drapes go with a purple carpet; peas go with carrots.

Unless you mean that a rock makes a balloon more appealing, even if the rock is tied to the balloon, it does not “go with it”.  It comes with it.

**Edit:** in the comments, there is some consensus that in addition to “aesthetic compatibility” the expression *go with* can indicate mechanical or practical compatibility: “The ¾" nut goes with the ¾" bolt.” “That lid does not go with that much bigger pot.” “I lost the remote that goes with that TV.”

Comment: "Said about an inanimate object, it means something entirely different: that one thing is aesthetically compatible with the other" - or else that the objects in question belong together, for example "this lid goes with that jar".

Comment: @DanParsonson — you aren’t wrong but if someone told me “this lid goes with that jar” I would first think that they meant it matched or contrasted in visually pleasing ways.  Mechanical compatibility would be secondary; I would prefer to say the lid _fit_ the jar or _belongs_ to the jar.

Comment: @MichaelLorton Regional differences maybe, but I definitely wouldn't think that.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that "come" and "go" are ordinarily opposites does not matter very much here, because neither one could be meant literally here. We are not talking about the literal movement of either the balloon or the stone - so we can only consider idioms that are based on metaphorical movement.

Thus:

"The stone comes with the balloon" means that the two objects are sold together.

"come with" could also mean to accompany; but this only really makes sense for people, not things.

"The stone goes with the balloon" would normally mean that they suit each other (belong together) somehow; but it's a little strange to say this about a stone and a balloon, because one would not ordinarily think that these two objects belong together.

There are [other meanings](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-with) for "go with", but they don't make sense for two objects (and not all of them are idiomatic in all dialects of English).

---

However, in your case, neither of these is idiomatic. "Go with" doesn't work: even if you thought that the stone and the balloon belonged together in some way (it does not simply mean that they are physically attached), it would be strange to use this to identify which stone you're talking about. "Come with", meanwhile, would have to be in the past tense - "came with". That's because you are referring to the event when you bought the stone and the balloon, which happened in the past.

If the point is to clarify which stone you're talking about, by mentioning that it's attached to the balloon, then just say that: "the stone attached to the balloon"; or "the stone which is attached to the balloon", or "the stone that is attached to the balloon".

In the situation you describe, though, it probably makes more sense to e.g. simply *point at* the stone and say "that stone".

Answer (score 0):

Neither because neither is correct. The stone isn’t dirty by design, and even if it was, you could get a defective balloon/stone combo where it was/is clean.

The correct phrase would be “**The stone attached to the balloon is dirty. Don't put it on the bed.**”

That is also your concern, the fact that it is **currently** dirty. Whether by design or happenstance, the stone is dirty and you don’t want the dirty stone put on the bed.

If it frequently gets dirty and you want to prevent bad habits, even if it may be clean now: “**The stone attached to the balloon is always getting dirty. Don't put it on the bed.**”

Answer (score -2):

You can say comes with/goes with **if you like**.
But that sounds like advertising lingo here in talking to a kid about a stone attached to a balloon string. Like for washing machines or parts. Or *unless  you are describing the balloons (or products) to someone.*

- This dress comes with a belt.
- This couch goes with that side table.

**For example**:

1. Perfect for both indoor and outdoor decorations, **these balloons come with a stick and stand for easy placement.**
   [balloons sold on the Internet](https://leighamarina.com/products/baby-shower-balloon-its-a-boy-11-light-blue-round-heart-shaped)
2. Confetti and Glitter Balloons **go with** any occasion! Give your event or occasion some extra “Pop” with these favourite party balloons!
   [balloons](https://skysthelimitbaskets.com/product/confetti-happy-birthday-balloon-bouquet/)

- Our balloons come with a pretty stone at the end of a string.
- The balloon comes with a stone on a string. [advertising]
- See John? The balloon comes with a stone on a string.

Speaking to someone about the dirty stone:

- **The stone on the balloon's string or balloon string is dirty. Don't put it on the bed.**

***go with/come with* can be used in tons of places and ways and it is impossible to give examples of all those places and ways**.

Comment: **goes with** is hardly advertising lingo. *A  small barometer goes with that thermometer hanging on the wall but it broke.*  And **comes with**, though it is often used when describing an item available for purchase, is just normal everyday speech. *That  car comes with front-wheel drive or all-wheel drive.*

Comment: @TimR **This sofa *goes with* a side table, in the same style as the other pieces of furniture**. //But you are not getting what I am saying: talking to  a kid about a dirty something, you would not use goes with/comes. In **this context** it sounds like advertising lingo re the balloon and stone hanging off the string. "goes with/comes" with can be used in tons of places but not here for the **meaning** the OP is seeking. We cannot be expected to show every single usage of goes with/comes with. Downvoters are clueless.

Comment: "Or unless you are describing the balloons to someone who has never seen one". But not to tell a kid not to put a dirty stone on the bed. I did specify that.

Comment: The downvoters aren't clueless; they just disagree with you. It doesn't sound particularly like advertising lingo to my native ear, to the extent that your assertion that it does seems rather bizarre.

Comment: @Tashus I gave two examples where it could sound like that, and for balloons. My answer is pretty much comprehensive for this **context**: the stone, the balloon, the string and the daughter. It is simply not something one says to one's daughter re something dirty like this (see the OP's wording): "the stone that goes with the balloon is dirty. Don't put it on the bed"? [buzzer]

Comment: @Lambie "It is simply not something one says to one's daughter re something dirty like this" I understand your assertion. I simply don't agree, and it seems that I am not alone in that regard. Providing examples of a word used in a context does not imply that it is only or even predominantly used in that context. Advertising uses the word "the", and I could provide plenty of examples. Would that mean that using "the" would sound like advertising lingo?

Comment: @Tashus Really "the"? [laughs] Perhaps you might have a look at the field of pragmatics. –